# Whats the name of the movie series with Parasite/Alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

So long ago I saw a movie/series dunno about insect like creatures that invaded human bodies by entering the mouth. They feed on sugar I believe and grow larger. There was a infected guy in a closet asking for sugar in the movie so that's why I think they feed on sugar. There was also a naked girl who walked around seducing men and when she kissed them they got the big ass parasite inside of them and that's how they got infected.

Answer (score 10):

[Candy Stripers (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0463935/)

> In a lonely road in Wucaipa, something attacks the driver of a car and
> her blind friend Tammy. They have a car accident; Tammy survives and
> is sent to the Wucaipa General Hospital. Meanwhile, a high school
> basketball team fights with the opponents in the square and the
> captain Matt with a broken leg, and his injured friends Joey and Brian
> are sent to the same hospital. **Tammy is near death and asks the candy
> striper nurse Janine to kiss her. While kissing as a gesture of
> sympathy, an alien invades the mouth of Janine and infects her**; she
> infects others nurses, clerks, doctors and patients, initiating an
> exponential virus outbreak in the hospital. Joey's sister Cherie that
> has a crush on Matt stays with them in the hospital. When Joey is
> infected by a hot nurse during the night, he has webbing on the face
> and rush, and Matt asks Cherie to call his girlfriend Krystal to help
> them to leave the hospital. **But the place is under quarantine and the
> candy stripers need sugar to procreate a breed of alien.**

Trailer:

Comment: Dear god that looks amazing.