# Story where hospital staff succumb to aliens and wear them close to their bodies

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I recently took some tries on Google but I was unable to identify the movie by its plot keywords alone, so here is a challenge for you:

The movie or episode is from the 90's or around 2000 maybe earlier. It could be an episode of something similar to *The Outer Limits* or *Twilight Zone*.

Its story is about a doctor who discovers his wife or girlfriend, a nurse working in the same hospital as himself, and most other nurses are possessed by dog embryo/puppy (no joke) like aliens they wear close to their bodies after having succumbed to them.

He finds a way to remove the alien from his wife/girlfriend and she then fights with him before he is able to free her.

They manage to find the alien nest and kill most of the aliens, but in the end she gets infected again and his attempts to stop the evil aliens fails (bad ending like many of *The Outer Limits* sci fi episodes).

I also think that at the start of the movie or episode, a close friend of the hero (a doctor like him) is dying which later turns out to be also caused by the aliens (he discovered something he wasn't meant to discover).

Comment: That sounds a bit like *The Puppet Masters*.

Comment: No, I know that movie, and it is not the one Im looking for. What Im looking for is more an episode than a movie, it had much a lower budget and as stated it had a bad ending (which is not the case in Puppet Masters).

Comment: Similarly, *Lost Tapes: Alien* is too late.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a bit later than you remember, it could be the 2006 [*Candy Stripers*](https://wickedhorror.com/horror-reviews/cult-corner-candy-stripers-2006/) (not to be confused with the [1978 porn film of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_Stripers_(film)))

> Candy Stripers begins with a blind girl taken into the ER after surviving a car crash. Unfortunately for everyone around, she’s not all that she appears to be and before dying passes an alien infection on to one of the nurses. It spreads like wildfire from there, and soon all of the nurses have been taken over. From there, the hospital staff begins to pick off men throughout the institution.
>
> Yes, it’s that kind of movie. The alien nurses spread the infection by making out with non-infected nurses which is actually not as hot as it sounds. When a tentacle thrusts out of one girl’s mouths and into the other’s it’s just kind of gross. Of course, they also pick off men by seducing them. It’s a bit hard to tell exactly what happens since they tend to just show the man scream, play an alien screech noise, and then cut away. Follow that by the man popping up in a cocoon.

### Trailer

Comment: While I can't remember the title, I do remember the show OP is talking about, and it was not gory like the movie

Comment: No, this is not what Im looking for.. As noted its not old enough and the show had a rather serious theme without gore and porn.

Comment: Fair enough. :) Good to rule it out.

Comment: Just quickly linking where this one came up before in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85174/whats-the-name-of-the-movie-series-with-parasite-alien

Answer (score 0):

Sound a bit like 1986 american horror movie Night of the Creeps.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add a brief synopsis or some relevant highlights?  It's better for the answer to be self-contained than need additional research.

Comment: The plot _Night of the Creeps_ isn't focused on a hospital. I don't recall it even featuring a hospital whatsover, so this doesn't seem like a good match. Yes, it has alien parasites in it, but there are quite a few films that do. A movie being proposed as an answer should include more than just that one element to be considered a good match.